# How to access model to provide data to external plugin?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using external plugin of datagrid.I need to pass json object to external plugin.

when i am trying to access model to collect data(json object) nothing is happening because it is class not object.

I have listed my code here :

Router :

```
        Grid.Router.map(function () {
      this.resource('mainview', { path: '/' });
        this.resource("modal", function(){
          this.route("new", {path:"/new"});
          this.route("edit", {path: "/:contact_id" });
        });           
    });  

    Grid.MainviewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
          model: function () {
            return Grid.ModalModel.find();
          }
        });

    Grid.GriddataRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
          model: function () {
                return Grid.ModalModel.find();
              }         
});
```

Model.js :

```
    Grid.ModalModel =  DS.Model.extend({
    fname: DS.attr('string'),
    lname: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    contactno: DS.attr('string'),
    gendertype: DS.attr('boolean'),
    contactype: DS.attr('number')
});

Grid.ModalModel.FIXTURES = [
                       {
                         id: 1,
                         fname: "ghg",
                         lname: "gh",
                         email: "gh",
                         contactno: "4542154",
                         gendertype: true,
                         contactype: 1,
                         action1:"",
                         action2:""
                       },
                       {
                         id: 2,
                         fname: "ghg",
                         lname: "gh",
                         email: "gh",
                         contactno: "4542154",
                         gendertype: true,
                         contactype: 1,
                         action1:"",
                         action2:""
                       },
                       {
                         id: 3,
                         fname: "ghg",
                         lname: "gh",
                         email: "gh",
                         contactno: "4542154",
                         gendertype: true,
                         contactype: 1,
                         action1:"",
                         action2:""
                       }
                      ];
```

Store.js :

```
Grid.Store = DS.Store.extend({
                  revision: 11,
                  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
                });
```

Controller :

```
return Grid.ModalModel.find();
```

here,view is accessing data from controller.In view (didInsertElement) i am calling external datagrid function and passing data as argument to this function.

I am getting following issue :

If i am trying to access data using `Grid.ModalModel.find()` i am getting class (refer following data from console.log)

```
Class {type: function, store: Class, isLoaded: true, isUpdating: true, toString: function…}
```

If i use `return this.get('controller.model')` i am getting `undefined`

When i am trying to convert `Grid.ModalModel.find()` to json object i am getting following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Can anyone tell me how to access model here to get data in json object format?

I trying to use following code

```
Grid.MainviewController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    contentChanged: function() {
        this.get('content').forEach(function(item){
          // doing item.toJSON() gives you a plain JSON object
          console.log(item.toJSON({includeId:true}));
        });
      }.observes('content.@each'),
      showmodal: function(){    
            $('#modal').modal(); 
    }
});
```

but `console.log(item.toJSON({includeId:true}));` throwing following error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toJSON'`

Comment: how are you trying to convert `Grid.ModalModel.find()` to JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a `controller` for the respective routes and define there a computed property which binds on the `content`, the CP function get's fired every time the content changes.

Something like this:

```
Grid.MainviewController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  contentChanged: function() {
    this.get('content').forEach(function(item){
      // doing item.toJSON() gives you a plain JSON object
      console.log(item.toJSON({includeId:true}));
    });
  }.observes('content.@each')
});
```

Then use the `DS.Model` built-in method `toJSON()` to get a JSON representation of your records.

See [here](http://jsbin.com/odosoy/10/edit) for a demo.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice answer @intuitivepixel. I don't knew about the `toJSON`, and don't get success in observing the content, maybe because I was observing from route instead controller. Just one advice, observing `model.isUpdating`, will trigger less often than `content.@each`.

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior, thanks for the advice, but do you mean observing `model.isUpdating` from a route or controller?

Comment: In controller, like you have done. Instead of `observes('content.@each')`, use `.observes('model.isUpdating')`. And in begin of the method `if (this.get('model.isUpdating')) { return; }`, to not execute while is loading.

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior, strange... it's not working (http://jsbin.com/odosoy/8/edit) the observer never fires

Comment: your first fiddle too (http://jsbin.com/odosoy/2/edit) and I saw this working. Maybe something is wrong with jsbin :(

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior, yeah it must be jsbin related :/ I have just tried the jsbin (http://jsbin.com/odosoy/2/edit) from my answer and it seams to work... but who knows for how long :/